# Search only subscribed channels in YouTube

Tags: youtube, search

Is it possible to search for a video in YouTube only in the channels one has subscribed (and not in all possible channels)?

Comment: Hard to believe that this is still not possible, but it seems to be the case.

Comment: I use youtube-dl and a script to download all video titles and descriptions of each subscribed channel into one huge text file. Then I can search in that file for that one video I watched a year ago but could only remember one word of the title :-)

Comment: Keep in mind, YouTube supports RSS feeds out of the box for all channels, thus making them searchable, using a good RSS reader. You can convert any channel to an RSS feed by typing this URL: https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=[CHANNEL_ID]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you are asking for is not possible, YouTube has no such feature.

Comment: While your answer is technically true it ignores a feature that is described in the answer by Ali Raza that CAN be used to solve the OP's request, albeit with multiple searches, but with much more targeted and useful results than the open search that you imply is the only search possible.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the Subscribed channel.
2. You'll find a magnifying glass just right to about link underneath channel title.
3. Click it, provide search query and enter, you'll have the results from withing that channel.

Comment: That works for only one channel, the question asks about multiple channels.

Comment: Yes the question implies multiple channels but there are 2 reasons this is a great answer
1. While you may have to do this procedure multiple times at least you search all channels
2. The question my have been slightly less specific than intended.  If a person has multiple channels it's likely there are multiple interests and a search of "all channels" is at least somewhat likely to be nearly as irrelevant as a search irrespective of channels.  So this answer both gives a way to do what the OP wanted, albeit tediously, AND give the way to do a much better search in my opinion.